# Grails controllers dynamic finders

Tags: grails, controllers

I'm kinda new to Grails so I need help with this matter. Imagine I have these classes:

```
Class User{
String name
String nr

}

class Computer{

String processor
String ram
User user
}

Class Room{
String roomNr
Computer computer
}
```

I want to do a controller like this:

```
def print= {

        def user = User.get(1)

        def computer = Computer.findAllByUser(user) // all computers filtered by User

        [computer: computer]       
    }
```

The controller works good, but I want to be able to pass not only the computer instances, but also the Room's with that computer id's. I dont know how to do it, but would be something like this (same controller, same action):

```
def print= {

            def user = User.get(1)

            def computer = Computer.findAllByUser(user) // all computers filtered by User
            def room = Room.findAllByComputer(computer) ##

            [computer: computer]       
        }
```

Well, this is wrong because, where the ### is, 'computer' represents a list of id's and not a single id. As I am passing a list of computers to be printed in my gsp inside a g: each tag like this: (it. Processor, it. Ram). I dont know how to get all the rooms which are using the current computer in the each tag. This is a bit hard to explain, but basically my output would be:

```
<g:each in="${computer}"
Computer1:
Processor: ${it.processor}
Ram: ${it.ram}
Room: ????? (How to get here??)
</g:each>
```

PS. i cannot do it one-to-many bidirectional because, if i have a foreign key in the room table poitinng to computer table, that means each room line must have one computer reference. And that can happen or **not**. So im looking for a solution for my issue.

Comment: don't duplicate post.  work with us in your original question. we'll get you sorted ;)